# cant list Hadoop filesystem

Tags: exception, hadoop, hdfs

I'm trying to run Hadoop on a banana pi and I don't understand why my Hadoop isn't working.

I have an **exception** on running the very basic command

```
root@bananapi:/opt/hadoop# hadoop fs -ls
14/12/17 10:27:13 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your     platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
ls: Call From bananapi/10.0.2.150 to localhost:9000 failed on connection exception:        
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:      http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused
root@bananapi:/opt/hadoop#
```

I have installed the followed **jdk**

```
root@bananapi:/opt/hadoop# java -version
java version "1.7.0_65"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.5.3) (7u71-2.5.3-2~deb7u1)
OpenJDK Zero VM (build 24.65-b04, mixed mode)
```

My **etc/hosts** file is looking like this:

```
root@bananapi:/opt/hadoop# cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost
10.0.2.150  bananapi  # wlan0
10.0.2.119  bananapi  # eth0
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0     ip6-localnet
ff00::0     ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1     ip6-allnodes
ff02::2     ip6-allrouters
```

The services (**jps**) is also running:

```
root@bananapi:/opt/hadoop# jps
3732 NodeManager
3317 NameNode
3644 ResourceManager
3401 DataNode
3513 SecondaryNameNode
3860 Jps
```

**What I'm doinging wrong or why is commands not working?**
P.S. I have also tried to run `hdfs dfs -ls`

### UPDATE

my confs in the **core-site.xml**

```
<property>
  <name>fs.default.name</name>
  <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
</property>
```

I also can't **format** the namenode

```
hadoop namenode -format
```

Comment: problem in configuration file..Do update question with your core-site.xml.

Comment: @Rengasamy I have added the core-site.xml ..... Any idea now?